# Forcing AngularJS to reload updated value on html end

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, dynamic-programming

I have a timer that I am writing as my first application in AngularJS. I have been trying to teach myself angular but I believe there may be a fundamental disconnect in how I have my model set up. Although I can see the updated values in the web console via my console.log print outs, the timer on the html side is not appearing to update.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('countdownTimer', []);


myApp.service('timerService',['$http','$timeout', function($http, $timeout){
 var time = 180;
 var self = this;

 this.getPrettyTime = function(){
  var minutes = time/60;
  var seconds = time - minutes * 60;
  if (seconds < 10){
   myDateObject.date = minutes + ":0" + seconds; 
  }
  else{
   myDateObject.date = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }
  return myDateObject;
 }
 
 var myDateObject = {
  date: null
 }
 var onTimeout = function() {
  time = time - 1;
  if (time > 0){
   console.log(time);
   mytimeout = $timeout(onTimeout, 1000);
   
  }
  else{
   time = 180;   
   mytimeout = $timeout(onTimeout, 1000);
  }
 }
 this.start = function() {
  
  $timeout(onTimeout, 1000);
 }

 
}]);

myApp.controller('CounterController', ['$timeout','$scope', 'timerService', function($timeout, $scope, timerService){
 /**$scope.counter = 180;
 **/
 //var date = new Date(null);
 //date.setSeconds(timerService.getTime());
 $scope.myDateObject = timerService.getPrettyTime();
 
 
 $scope.start = function(){
  timerService.start();
 
 }
 
 $scope.stop = function(){
  $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
 }
 
 
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Example </title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app2.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body data-ng-app="countdownTimer">
 <div data-ng-controller="CounterController">
  {{myDateObject.date}}
  <button data-ng-click="stop()">Stop</button>
  <button data-ng-click="start()">Start</button>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the example above, the timer is not updating on the webpage. Is there a disconnect in my logic (I am new to angular so I would love to learn where I went wrong) or am I misinterpreting angular functionality altogether?

Thanks

Comment: From your code I can tell that nothing is updating `myDateObject`, you need a code that will update this value, but your logic design doesn't look promising to do it

Comment: Agreed with @codtex. I spent a good amount of time trying to make it work around your existing code but it doesn't seem very feasible. Look into restructuring a bit so that `myDateObject` can be updated in the controller based upon service changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in **getPrettyTime** you need to do :

```
var minutes = Math.floor(time/60);
```

Else you will get a float number.

After that you need to call your **getPrettyTime** function every time your time is updated, so you can do this in your **onTimeout** function like this :

```
var onTimeout = function() {
    time = time - 1;
    self.getPrettyTime();
    ...
```

Here is a working snippet :

```js
var myApp = angular.module('countdownTimer', []);


myApp.service('timerService', ['$http', '$timeout', function($http, $timeout) {
  var time = 180;
  var self = this;

  self.getPrettyTime = function() {
    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var seconds = time - minutes * 60;
    if (seconds < 10) {
      myDateObject.date = minutes + ":0" + seconds;
    } else {
      myDateObject.date = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
    return myDateObject;
  }

  var myDateObject = {
    date: null
  }
  var onTimeout = function() {
    time = time - 1;
    self.getPrettyTime();
    if (time > 0) {
      console.log(time);
      mytimeout = $timeout(onTimeout, 1000);

    } else {
      time = 180;
      mytimeout = $timeout(onTimeout, 1000);
    }
  }
  this.start = function() {

    $timeout(onTimeout, 1000);
  }


}]);

myApp.controller('CounterController', ['$timeout', '$scope', 'timerService', function($timeout, $scope, timerService) {
  /**$scope.counter = 180;
   **/
  //var date = new Date(null);
  //date.setSeconds(timerService.getTime());
  $scope.myDateObject = timerService.getPrettyTime();


  $scope.start = function() {
    timerService.start();

  }

  $scope.stop = function() {
    $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
  }


}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Example </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app2.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="countdownTimer">
  <div data-ng-controller="CounterController">
    {{myDateObject.date}}
    <button data-ng-click="stop()">Stop</button>
    <button data-ng-click="start()">Start</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured this out myself and was going to post a similar solution but yours seems much more elegant! Cheers.

Comment: @sudobangbang You should also consider using $interval instead of $timeout https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval